# How can I find the entity which is used most in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find the id and name of the chef who cooks the most in these tables, and how many dishes he/she cooks. Of course from `food` table through the `chef_id`.

How can I do that?

[Here is cheff table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqpSP.jpg)

[image]

[Here is the food table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqDYP.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Images of data really don't help us; especially when it's more than one or 2 very "thin" rows. Take the time to post the data in a consumable format; preferably DDL and DML statements, but we can at least use well formatted tabular `text`. Don't forget too show us what you've tried as well. Explain why the attempts didn't work and what research *you* have don't to solve the problem and what about the articles/tutorials/documentation you didn't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the top chef (or chefs) simply aggregate the count per unique Id and join to the Chefs

```
select c.[Name], f.qty
from (
    select top (1) with ties chef_id
    from Food
    group by chef_id
    order by Count(*) desc
)f
join cheff c on c.Id=f.Chef_id
```

Comment: This partially solves it, but what I really need is which chef cooks the most and the name of that chef.

Comment: @ErenBerkSaltaş I don't follow you, `c.[name]` is the name of the chef; use `c.*` if you want all columns.

Answer (score 1):

You need `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
  chef.id,
  chef.name,
  COUNT(food.chef_id)
FROM
  chef
  INNER JOIN food ON chef.id = food.chef_id
GROUP BY
  chef.id,
  chef.name
ORDER BY 
  COUNT(food.chef_id) DESC
```

This will show each chef and how many meals they cooked, with the chef who cooked the most meals at the top, and the rest in descending order.

More info: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/sql-group-by-clauses-explained/

Comment: This partially solves it, but what I really need is which chef cooks the most and the name of that chef.

Comment: @ErenBerkSaltaş well if you order it by the count (descending) it will show the one who cooked the most meals at the top - see edited answer